# NSwag.MSBuild generate a single C# client class methods without controller name prefix

Tags: nswag

I use `NSwag.MSBuild` to generate the swagger.json file from the .net API controller. Then generate the C# client from the swagger.json file.

In nswag.json, I set `"operationGenerationMode": "SingleClientFromOperationId"` under `openApiToCSharpClient`. However, C# client method names are generated with the pattern `<controller>_<actionMethod>`. I only wanted to generate a single client with `<actionMethod>` without the prefix `<controller>_`.

With the `NSwag.MSBuild` tool:

For `webApiToOpenApi` generation, is there a setting to generate operationId without the `<controller>_` prefix?

Or is there a setting in `openApiToCSharpClient` to generate methods to ignore `<controller>_` prefix?